# Capture pen strokes using styluspoints

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, stylus-pen

I am trying to use [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.ink.stroke.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Ink_Stroke__ctor_System_Windows_Input_StylusPointCollection_) to capture inkstrokes. When I try to run this code, it says missing assembly reference error. I searched over the internet and found it should work on using System.Windows.Ink namespace, but it isn't working.

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The documents you view are not UWPs.

If you want to know how UWP apps use strokes, check out this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.input.inking.inkstroke).

This is a [description](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/input/pen-and-stylus-interactions) of how to use Ink, maybe it can help you.

Best regards.